# Where do I get the boots of introspection?

Tags: candy-box-2

I've looked all over for them with no luck. The only things left for me to do are the Dragon's quests, and I still can't find these things!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drink X potion, after that you'll fight with Yourself. But you can't just kill Yourself without killing yourself (Logic) so you need NON-enchanted Octopus King's Crown. Then you'll get Boots of Introspection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an X potion, use it during a fight, and to win the fight that it puts you into.

Answer (score 0):

Use the X potion, and you'll fight yourself. but you have to use the Octopus King's Crown. Then you'll get da boots.

Comment: Hey matt, welcome to Arqade. In the future, if a question has already been answered, it's best to only add a new answer if there's some new information not mentioned in the others.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make and use an X potion and fight yourself, but you need the regular Octopus King's Crown to do so.